# jQuery: how to pass event metadata on HTML elements while maintaining XHTML validity?

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I have a block-level HTML element that contains multiple block-level and inline-level elements, e.g.

```
<div id="ajax">
   <h2>Something</h2>
   <div class="icon"></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="somethingelse"><h3>blah</h3></div>
</div>
```

I simply want to attach a jQuery ajax() event to a click on #ajax (the top-level element), but I need to pass through a few parameters to the server-side script.

One possible way I'm seeing is simply replacing `div#ajax` with `a#ajax`, which would allow me to add something like `href="param=value&this=that"`, but this would render the page invalid: there can't be any block-level elements (`<div>`) inside of an inline element (`<a>`).

Another possible way would be adding a `rel` attribute to `div#ajax`, which would also mean neglecting XHTML validation.

I don't want to go adding inline `onclick` events to divs, that's a little too far out... Also, turning all children of `div#ajax` into e.g. `<span>` would be a major pita.

How would you handle this?

Comment: Maybe you can bind a function that dynamically requests the ajax to the #ajax. You question is quite vague, the script or an example will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this while maintaining XHTML validity, or at least remaining full functional in all browsers:

First option, put the parameters directly in JavaScript somewhere, this is the simplest.

---

Second, if you can't do this in the script, you can use the anchor, but *inside*, not wrapping it, like this:

```
<div id="ajax">
   <h2>Something</h2>
   <div class="icon"></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="somethingelse"><h3>blah</h3></div>
   <a class="params" href="page.htm?param=value&this=that"></a>
</div>
```

CSS Hiding it:

```
.params { display: none; }
```

And jQuery using it:

```
$("#ajax").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: $(this).find(".params").attr("href");
     success: function() {
       //do something
     }
   });
});
```

---

Third, use [HTML5 data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), this will break strict XHTML validity, but a great future way to go, it'll cause no problems in current browsers.

---

Last option (that I can think of), use the [jQuery metadata plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata) or storing what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I like the added link inside and I really love the HTML5 approach. That one will also break transitional XHTML validity, but right now I think I'm taking that too seriously anyway... I'll probably end up doing that after all. Thanks!